# IE 11 not showing Adobe Edge HTML5 animations

Tags: html, animation, internet-explorer-11

Since upgrading to a new Windows 8, IE 11 laptop I have discovered that any Adobe Edge HTML5 animations are not showing, this is a problem! Does anyone have a solution or has anyone experienced this as well?  Is there a better option for HTML5 animation? Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Found this link - http://blogs.adobe.com/edge/2013/08/07/update-to-edge-animate-cc-is-here-fixing-compatibility-issues-with-ie11/  apparently it is a known issue with IE11.

Comment: @tremor Could you post that link as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Abode there is a compatibility issue with IE11, explained in the following link:  http://blogs.adobe.com/edge/2013/08/07/update-to-edge-animate-cc-is-here-fixing-compatibility-issues-with-ie11/

Steps on updating edge are contained within the article.